# Complex SQL Queries (self joins and left joins)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables Department and Employees. Department has department information and each row is a different department identified by deptID and the name is DeptName. Within each row there is an DeptHeadID which holds the employee ID of the manager for that department.

Employees has employee information where each row is a different employee identified by EmpID, their name is Name and each row has a deptID that points to the department table.

I'm trying to figure out how to find out how to list the manager name and employee names for each department. I can list the manager ID number and employee name but going from manager ID to manager name is stumping me.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus, is this Oracle?

Comment: yes i'm using the SQL Plus command line that came with oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly the same than going from Employee to Department.

Of course, if you only use one "copy" of the Employee table, the `WHERE` clause (`EmployeeId = ManagerId`) would filter out all employees who are not managers, so maybe you must use more than one copy.

```
SELECT ....
    from Employee empl1, -- Use this to get the data of the employees
         Department dep, -- Join empl1 to find the employee department
         Employee empl2, -- Join dep with this to get the manager data
```

Comment: If you do an `OUTER JOIN` (or also `(+)` in Oracle) you will not filter out the employees whose department has no manager...

Comment: i'm not quite following you if I do:

SELECT Name, DeptHeadID 
FROM Employees, Department
WHERE Employees.DeptID=Department.DeptID;

I get the DeptHeadID and employees listed for each department but I want the Name of the DeptHeadID but Name is in Employees table. So I can't figureout how to go from DeptHeadID in Department to get the Name of the matching EmpID in Employees table

Comment: That's why you need the `Employee` table to be joined **twice**. Even if it is the same table, you can use `emp1` and `emp2` independently (one to get the employee data, the other to get the manager)

Answer (score 0):

something like this using subquery

```
select empname,deptname,
(select empname from Employees where empid = DeptHeadID) as Managers
from
(
select e.empname,d.deptname,d.DeptHeadID from Employees e join 
Departments d on e.deptID = d.deptID 
) tab
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.department_id,
       a.manager_id,
       b.employee_id,
       b.first_name EmployeeName,
       b.ManagerName 
from (
    select d.department_id,
           d.manager_id
    from departments  d
) a
,(
    select manager_id,
           employee_id,
           first_name,
           (select first_name from employees b 
             where b.employee_id=a.manager_id) as ManagerName
    from employees a
) b
where a.manager_id=b.manager_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding SJuan76's answer to allow for a direct copy-paste:

```
SELECT dep.department_id,
       dep.manager_id,
       empl1.employee_id,
       empl1.first_name EmployeeName,
       empl2.first_name ManagerName 
FROM Employee empl1 -- Use this to get the data of the employees
JOIN Department dep -- Join empl1 to find the employee department
  ON empl1.deptID = dep.deptID
JOIN Employee empl2 -- Join dep with this to get the manager data
  ON empl2.deptID = dep.manager_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select e.ename MGRNAME,m.ename EMPNAME from emp e join emp m on e.empno = m.mgr;

This might help you.